# Quel équivalent du "edit" anglais utilisez-vous ?

Tags: expressions, anglicismes

Le terme "edit" est couramment utilisé sur le web anglais (et par les Français qui s'y retrouvent). On s'en sert pour parler d'un changement ou d'une correction réalisée au cours de la ré-édition (du texte d'un article de blogue par exemple, ou d'un code).

Cet anglicisme offre l'avantage d'être court et de préciser en 4 lettres que le texte qu'il accompagne est un changement et donc qu'il a été rajouté et donc ré-édité (d'où "édit"). Difficile donc de faire plus simple et plus sobre.

Je me demandais quel équivalent était utilisé par les anti-anglicistes, disons dans l'exemple suivant ou dans le cas où l'auteur chercherait à signaler une correction

> cela ce passera comme ci et comme ça suivi d'un paragraphe de blabla...
>
> Edit (ou Édit) : suite à cet événement (ou : il s'agissait d'une erreur), cela se passera plutôt comme ça.

"Mis à jour" me semble plutôt lourd et déplacé dans ce contexte (comme "update" d'ailleurs). Qu'en pensez-vous ? Et vous, quel terme utilisez-vous ?

Comment: Pour *edit* au sens du titre de votre question, on utilise ***modifier***. Pour *edit* au sens de l'exemple que vous avez cité, on utilise bel et bien ***mise à jour***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'avantage du terme anglais est de couvrir de nombreux cas:

- éditer qui est correct en français, a bien un sens en relation dans le domaine de l'édition (sic!) et est très compréhensible;
- plutôt *rédiger* (domaine journalistique);
- **modifier** pour une mise à jour (le plus correct);
- et même monter pour les films.

Comme le terme anglais correspond à la fois à la rédaction initiale ou mise à jour, la *mixture* « éditer » pourrait aussi fonctionner et est proche de « edit ».

Answer (score 4):

"MàJ" un acronyme de Mis à jour, me semble tout à fait correct et compréhensible. Il a l'avantage d'être plus court que sa version anglaise.

Un autre acronyme, "PS" de Postscriptum signifie littéralement que la mention citée a été écrite ultérieurement. Généralement utilisé dans le genre épistolaire, et surtout en marge de bas de page...

Une autre solution peut-être de d'annoter avec un chiffre ou une lettre et d'insérer la nouvelle version en bas de page. Technique généralement utilisé dans les livres.

Comment: merci pour ta suggestion ! Effectivement c'est plus court (bon argument !) mais comme milk2go je trouve que ça sonne un peu logiciel informatique.

Answer (score 2):

Étant donné qu'un *edit* a souvent une des deux vocations suivantes :

- rajouter du texte à la fin du message ;
- amender le corps d'un message.

Il ne me semble pas qu'il y est un seul mot qui couvre ces deux usages.

Pour le premier usage, un anti-anglisciste peut recourir à l'expression latine *addendum*.

> **addendum** \a.dœ̃.dɔm\ masculin (orthographe traditionnelle)
>        Ajout à un document, note additionnelle.

Cependant, l'académie francaise ne reconnait que la forme plurielle *addenda*. Plus simplement, « ajout » peut très bien suffir.

Pour le second usage, le plus simple est à mon avis de marquer en début de message « le corps de ce message a été amendé/modifié. » ou tout simple « message amendé. »

Comment: Il faut noter généralement que _addenda_ peut être employé pour désigner le singulier : un addenda. ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/addenda), [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/addenda/1008/difficulte)). Enfin [certains](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8369091) préfèrent l'intégration complète du mot latin, avec la marque du pluriel (_addendas_).

Answer (score 1):

Personnellement, si tu me disais addendum je n'aurais aucune idée de quoi tu parles. Mis à jour semble tendre vers un logiciel informatique. Le terme le plus général pour "edit" serait: **modifier**. C'est ce qu'on voit dans les sites quand on peut modifier du texte, une annonce etc...

Comment: idem concernant "Mis à jour" et "addendum"

Answer (score 1):

La meilleure traduction pour "edit", pour moi, est "modifié(e)"

Answer (score 1):

Je conseillerai :

- [*Mise à jour*](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/mettre-a-jour/) : Si tu publies les modifications ou si c'est plusieurs modifications.

  > Actualiser, moderniser, rajeunir. **Action de mettre en conformité**, de faire correspondre à l'état actuel du progrès, du savoir ou en fonction des dernières innovations, des derniers développements.
- *[Modification](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/modification/51965?q=modification#51841)* : Pour une édition/un changement.

  > Intervention faite sur quelque chose, qui le modifie, le transforme, le change plus ou moins **sans en altérer la nature essentielle** : Apporter quelques modifications à un texte.

Tu peux aussi utiliser *Révision* :

- [*Révision*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/r%C3%A9vision/69135) :

  > Action d'examiner de nouveau, de mettre à jour, de modifier : Révision d'un texte.

Pour un document écrit tu as aussi : *[correction](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/correction/19424)*, *[rectification](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rectification/67214)*, *[adptation](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/adaptation/1003)*.